# Android co-routine indicate that code will be running from off UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I want to access my database from inside an OkHttp SkipInterceptor.  Here is a code snippet

```
    private fun makeOkResult(request: Request): Response {
        var responseBody: JobsResponse

        val value = GlobalScope.async { // creates worker thread
                 withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                JobsResponse(database.jobDao.getJobs(), "success")
            }
        }


        return Response.Builder()
            .code(200)
            .request(request)
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .message("OK")
            .body(ResponseBody.create(
                MediaType.get("application/json"),
                gson.toJson(value.await())))
            .build()
    }
}
```

The problem is that the kotlin compiler is not allowing me to call value.await() on the UI Thread.  I know that this code will never run on the UI Thread because OkHttp will run it on a networking thread.  Is there any way for me to indicate that this is safe and will not be running on the UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not that this is being called from the UI thread. You are trying to wait for a suspend function from a non-suspend one which is impossible.

Exactly how to implement this type of behavior is heavily depended on where/how it is being used.

Comment: So this is a bit of a strange case that would never end up in a production environment.  I want to access my repository object that wraps around my Dao to fake API calls with real app data.  I am also using fixture objects so i instead used those but it is not a good solution as it won't be enough when I add the ability to create new jobs and save them to the database.  Perhaps I could run this from the application scope somehow?

Comment: If it'll only run in a test, the best option is to simply use runBlocking or runTest after turning this function into a suspend function.